# On new page, scrolling down to a specific div automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, scroll, sections

Quite simple,

I would like on click, to arrive to a specific section on a new page.

Usually `www.mydomain.com/page1/#section` should work, `#section` being the ID of the section.

However, the menu I'm using is breaking this. Si I'm trying to see if it's possible to do this by Jquery, using Hash. ( When url have this hash example www.myd0main.com/page/#contact - do this)

SO far I tried the following:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {


         if (window.location.hash.split('-')[0] == '#contact') {
    $('#contact').addClass('hashed');
}

 });
</script>
```

Withotu any sucess.

Do you guys have any turnaround / idea to make this work ?

It will be lovely !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
if (window.location.hash == '#contact') {
  // Scroll to #contact 
  $(document).scrollTop($("#contact").offset().top);
}
```

Comment: Your code work If i disable the menu plugins, so it's related to that, but I was hopping that Jquery will break this, apparently no :(

Comment: Fixed by removing the js of this plugin.

Thank you for your time :)